# use Line chart from highchart

Tags: c#, highcharts, asp.net-core, linechart

I am going to use Line chart from highchart library in my .NetCore C# project. I am fairly new to this matter. Following all highcharts.net instruction looks everything is easy. I have copied

```
<highchart:LineChart id="hcVendas" runat="server" Width="500" Height="350" />
```

in the About.cshtml and left below code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        //Defining Axis

        hcVendas.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("Faturamento") });
        hcVendas.XAxis.Add(new XAxisItem { categories = new[] { "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002" } });

        //New data collection
        var series = new Collection<Serie>();
        series.Add(new Serie { data = new object[] { 400, 435, 446, 479, 554, 634, 687, 750, 831 } });

        //bind 
        hcVendas.DataSource = series;
        hcVendas.DataBind();
        if (User.IsInRole("Adminstrators"))
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

But I receive error "Error  CS0103  The name 'hcVendas' does not exist in the current context"
Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is really old sample code. Looks like these are for the web forms user controls

Comment: Hi Shyju, Do you know any other chart which can be used in .netCore? I don't use scaffolding.

Comment: you can use any other client side charting libraries. google charts is something i recently used

Comment: Thanks Shyju, Good guide. I will work on that. Cheers

Comment: @FaridFarzin Here: http://dotnet.highcharts.com/ you can find examples of various Highcharts charts build in .NET.

Comment: If you need, re ask you question from earlier today. I was posting an answer as you deleted.

Comment: I returned it Ryan.